# Word to edit textbox controls without checking them out

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

i have a word document on my documentlibrary. is it possible to open the document, make changes then print or send this document as mail and close it, without checking out?

For example: there is a vacation request document on my library and the user should not edit the document on library but the fill out the vacation request ans send this with mail to me.

sorry for my bad english.

regards mario

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to download the word file, make changes and send it as email, you cant enforce user not to edit the file,

but I don't understand why you need this based on the scenario you have described above, a custom list is the best solution for you, create a custom list with all the fields you want (as you said fill out the vacation request), user can also attach some file if they want, and they will submit the form, that's your purpose right? you can export all entries in excel format any time you want, and if you really want that the entries should come to your mail then setup a workflow against the list such that if someone enters the detail and submit the form a mail will trigger to you with all the submitted details

you can also consider InfoPath forms

Comment: On my library there are many documents for user requests. it is not possible to crate for every request a new custom list.

is it posible to download the word file by click on the name and not start word for edit?

Comment: no it's not possible, first of all a word file can always be opened with word, you cant restrict users action after they have downloaded the file, what will user do with the file if they cant open or edit it? your situation can be handled only by web form or maybe infopath, can you please describe your situation, like how many word files are there? and if these word files are each a form, and if every form has separate fields

Comment: ok here are the situation:
i had a document library and all documents are approved by a supervisor. When a user create a new File (e.g. vacation request) they implements textboxes and controls. he save the document on library and start the approval workflow. 
when another user want to fill out this document, he must check out it for write text in the textboxes. i need a solution where a user fill out the document without checkout.

Comment: i think web form is your best shot with the kind of requirement you have

Answer (score 0):

Assign custom permission on the document library, so that users have only read only access. This means they would have to download the vacation request and fill it and mail it to you.

Hope this helps, please free to ask if you have any other questions

Cheers!